# Maven 2 replace class implementation depending on profile

Tags: maven, maven-2, replace

I have `MailTransport.java` and two classes extending it: `LiveMailTransport.java` and `TestMailTransport.java`.
`LiveMailTransport` will really send emails while `TestMailTransprot` will only write them to the log for testing purpose.

Somewhere I do `new MailTransport();` and I would like to replace every usage of `MailTransport` in my server-side code either with `Live-` or with `TestMailTransport` depending on the profile used for compiling (local, production, etc..).

(Similar to gwts "replace-with" on client side...)

How could I do that with Maven?

Comment: Are you using src/main/java and src/test/java ?

Comment: @khmarbaise: yes but we have much more profiles for test servers, cont.integration, etc with different mail-transport implementations..

Comment: That sounds like you need a single Test suite against an interface which can be used with serveral different implementations.

Comment: this question is not about testing... its about replacing a class/implementation used in the source code for different environments like a strategy-pattern using maven.

Comment: As i already wrote this is the intention of an DI framework and NOT of Maven. In particulr if you have the strategy-pattern in use. This is definitely a task for a DI framework. You have to think about your testing strategy. If you need different strategies for dev, test or production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a factory which accepts a system property. If the system property isn't set, create an instance of `LiveMailTransport`. If the property is there, create an instance of `TestMailTransport`.

Proposed name of property: `com.pany.app.enableTestMails`

[Boolean.getBoolean(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) is your friend.

Now [configure the surefire plugin to set the property](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a misuse of Maven, cause this looks more like dependency injection task (guice for example) but there is no relationship with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring or some other dependency injection framework you could manipulate dependencies injected based on inclusion of corresponding configuration.

But if you want to do it with a plain bare bone Java application you could create multiple factories that will create corresponding instances of yoor MailTransport and place these factories into a different source folders. Then use [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to add correspoinding source folder based on active profiles.